# svn reintegrate gives strange conflicts

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tree-conflict

I am having trouble reintegrating a feature branch back into the trunk using Tortoise SVN (v 1.7.13).  Project A had some work going on in the trunk and for some other work we need to do in parrallel, we created a branch.  Now that the branch work is complete we are trying to reintegrate it back into the trunk.

I did the following steps:
1 - checkout trunk
2 - merge/reintegrate branch
3 - resolved the conflicts
4 - commit

Here is what I don't understand.
1 - The conflicts that I get on 3 don't make sense.  It says that a folder was deleted from the branch, but that folder does not exist in the branch or the trunk.
2 - After committing if I do merge/reintegrate again, all the conflicts come back.  It is like I never did it.